# How to change Property of Selected View

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to make some changes in Label or StackLayout. I want after clicking on item, change textcolor or backgroundcolor for example. After i click at Bought in Context Menu, it gives me: Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is XAML code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="productsList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Label  x:Name="{Binding ProdListId}" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium"/>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Text="ADD" Clicked="AddProducts"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

C#:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        productsList.ItemsSource = App.Database.GetProductListItems(ListID);
        base.OnAppearing();
    }


    private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Choose action", "Cancel", null, "Delete", "Bought");
        switch (action)
        {
            case "Delete":
                Product selectedProduct = (Product)e.SelectedItem;
                App.Database.DeleteProductOfListItem(selectedProduct.ProdListId);
                // this.Navigation.PopAsync();
                OnAppearing();
                break;

            case "Bought":
                Product selectedProduct2 = (Product)e.SelectedItem;
                App.Database.UpdateProductActive(true, selectedProduct2.ProdListId);                                                 
             var lbl = this.FindByName<Label>(selectedProduct2.ProdListId.ToString());
                lbl.TextColor = Color.Green;
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code where you set the `x:Name` of the label? Where is the code that calls `FindByName` in your C#?

Comment: i deleted it cause it doesnt work

Comment: The point of StackOverflow is to show what you tried, so people can help you find where you went wrong.

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Set your debugger on the `Bought` case and check if `selectedProduct2` is null or if it has no `ProdListId`.

Comment: selectedProduct2 is not null, it has Product object with 4 not null property values. ProdListId = 8

Comment: OK. Sorry, I'm not the best person to check XAML, as I've been working on web for awhile now. But I think maybe you can get the label from the `sender` object instead of searching for it?

Comment: thanks anyway. i will try